# Whole system is read only

Tags: wireless, nautilus, read-only

My whole system is read-only so I can't even connect to WiFi (needs authentication).

So I went into the terminal:

```
sudo su
nautilus
```

It sat there for about 20 seconds with no output then it had a bunch of errors then nautilus started.

I used that to go into `/usr/shared/applications` (or whatever) to launch "Disks" and it says nothing about being read-only.

So Im running on the terminal now as I can't use anything that writes settings or anything to the HDD.

Comment: What happens when you try to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mounting your hard drive in read-write mode; you should probably do this from recovery mode accessed in GRUB and drop to root terminal and use:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

Exit to recovery menu and resume normal boot, see if that does anything..

Comment: How do i go into recovery mode? Its at the GRUB menu right? cant see the option.

Comment: Recovery mode is usually underneath the Ubuntu option in GRUB [like so](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-m1Y1SeYErVI/UEyR609GntI/AAAAAAAAGWo/iIlc4NwTyOc/s1600/ubuntu-grub-menu-recovery-mode.png)

Comment: so do i just go in there and type that command?

Comment: In the recovery menu, you'll be presented with [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PjmRx.png). Hit "Root" and type the mount command, then type exit until you reach that menu again, from there select "resume" and see how your OS is then.

Comment: it also says there are "errors on /" and the fsck launches automatically on normal boot and says that whaen its suck on the ubuntu logo and i press "Esc"

Comment: sudo mount -o remount,rw /         just makes it say "mount: / not mounted or bad opton"

Comment: Do you know what specific identifier your Ubuntu is on? For example `dev/sda1`? You can access this information from the disk utility you are using or type `sudo parted` for GNU parted (if you can use authorization for that)

Comment: dev/sdb3. its fix now. all i had to do was fsck without options and it fixed it. everything is not read-only anymore and the file system is no longer corrupted